# Request new publish permission into a fragment

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments

I need to ask at the user to authorize publish permission if he dont do it.
I do it with this row of code:

```
//Into ShareOnFacebookFragment
Session.getActiveSession().requestNewPublishPermissions(new NewPermissionsRequest((SocialSharingActivity)getActivity(), "publish_actions"));
```

SocialSharingActivity is the Activity related to my Fragment (ShareOnFacebookFragment).
When I run the application the app correctly ask me the publish permission and I accept, but when I do publish I have this error in my logcat:

```
12-11 12:17:27.277: E/AndroidRuntime(29125): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Session: an attempt was made to request new permissions for a session that has a pending request.
```

Honestly my only hypotesis is that requestNewPublishPermissions run Async in background and then I have the problems when I try to publish. How I can solve this problem ? I post also my Entire fragment code

```
    private final String TAG = "ShareFragment";

private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
//   To allow a Fragment to communicate up to its Activity, you can define an interface in the Fragment class and implement it within the
//   Activity. The Fragment captures the interface implementation during its onAttach() lifecycle method and can then call the Interface methods in
//   order to communicate with the Activity.

private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {         //Provides asynchronous notification of Session state changes.
   @Override
   public void call(Session session, SessionState state,Exception exception) {
      onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
   }
};

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,Exception exception) {
   Log.i("CALLBACK: ", "Session state change: "+state);

   }


   @Override
   public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
       super.onAttach(activity);

       }
   @Override 
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
   uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   };
// This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
   // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
//   try {
//       mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) activity;
//   } catch (ClassCastException e) {
//       throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
//               + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
//   }
//}
  @Override
   public void onPause() {
     super.onPause();
     uiHelper.onPause();
  };
   @Override
      public void onResume() {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         super.onResume();
         uiHelper.onResume();
      }
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
       Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // Inflate the layout for this fragment
      RelativeLayout myRelative =  (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.share_frame, container, false);
      shareButton = (Button) myRelative.findViewById(R.id.shareButton);
      workoutIdTextView = (TextView) myRelative.findViewById(R.id.workoutIdTextView);
      objectCreatedTextView = (TextView) myRelative.findViewById(R.id.objectCreatedTextView);
      actionCreatedTextView = (TextView) myRelative.findViewById(R.id.actionCreatedTextView);


       return myRelative;
   }

   @Override
      public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
         uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
      }

   @Override
      public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
         uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

      }
   @Override
      public void onDestroy() {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         super.onDestroy();
         uiHelper.onDestroy();
      }
   @Override
      public void onStart() {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         super.onStart();

      }
   @Override
   public void onActivityCreated(Bundle bundle) {
      super.onActivityCreated(bundle);
      Log.i(TAG, "ONACTIVITYCREATED");
      SocialSharingActivity caller =(SocialSharingActivity) getActivity();
      Log.w(TAG, "caller "+caller.toString());
      workoutIdTextView.setText(String.valueOf(caller.getWorkoutId()));
      Log.i(TAG, "Data course " + caller.getEwCourse().toString());
      Log.i(TAG, "Message Run " + caller.getEwRun().toString());
      ewCourseFrag = caller.getEwCourse();
      ewRunFrag = caller.getEwRun();



      parAct=new Bundle();
      parAct.putAll(ewRunFrag.getParams());
      parObj = new Bundle();
      parObj.putString("access_token", APP_ACCESS_TOKEN);      
      gson = new Gson();
      parObj.putString("object", gson.toJson(ewCourseFrag));
      publishSession = Session.getActiveSession();
      //------------------------------Batch HTTP request-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      // 
      //------------------------------Declaration--and--implementation--of--Callback-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      RequestBatch.Callback batchCallback= new RequestBatch.Callback() {

         @Override
         public void onBatchCompleted(RequestBatch batch) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Batch completed: "+ "OK");

            //
         }
      };
      //
      Request.Callback reqCreateObjCallback= new Request.Callback() {

         @Override
         public void onCompleted(Response response) {


            if(response.getError() == null){
               Log.w(TAG,"reqCreateObjCallback: "+ "OK");
               objectCreatedTextView.setText("OK object");

            }
            else {
               Log.e(TAG,"reqCreateObjCallback: "+ response.getError().toString());
               Log.d(TAG, response.getError().getCategory().toString());
               objectCreatedTextView.setText(response.getError().getCategory().toString());
            }
            //400

         }

      };
      //
      Request.Callback reqPublishCallback= new Request.Callback() {

         @Override
         public void onCompleted(Response response) {


            if(response.getError() == null) {
               Log.w(TAG, "reqPublishCallback: "+ "OK");
               actionCreatedTextView.setText("OK action");

               //                   Toast.makeText(context, "ACTION_CREATED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {
               Log.e(TAG, "reqPublishCallback: "+ response.getError().toString());
               Log.d(TAG, response.getError().getCategory().toString());
               actionCreatedTextView.setText(response.getError().getCategory().toString());
            }
         }

      };
      //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

      //------------------------------Create--instance--of--RequestBatch--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      RequestBatch requestBatch= new RequestBatch();

      //------------------------------Request--for-create-the-graph-object---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      Request reqCreateObj= new Request(
            publishSession,  
            "app/objects/fitness.course", 
            parObj,HttpMethod.POST);                    //Create a Request for a common ObiectGraph of type course
      reqCreateObj.setCallback(reqCreateObjCallback);       //Set the callback for the Request
      reqCreateObj.setBatchEntryName("objectCreate");     //Tag the request name into the Batch with "objectCreate"
      requestBatch.add(reqCreateObj);                   //Add the request to the batch

      //------------------------------Request-for-publish-action-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      parAct.putString("course",
            "{result=objectCreate:$.id}");                 //Use the tag to retrieve the informations about the graph object created

      //can also add scrape flag to update the object
      //        par2.putString("end_time", new Date(new Date().getTime()+1000*60*2).toString()); // live text test
      Request reqPublish = 
            new Request(publishSession,        //Create a request for publish an action relative to the object;
                  // Similarly at a  phrase, an action is like "verbo", graph object
                  "me/fitness.runs/",parAct,              //is like "complemento oggetto" and the the user is "soggetto"
                  HttpMethod.POST);                      //
      reqPublish.setCallback(reqPublishCallback);            //Set the callback for the Request
      requestBatch.add(reqPublish);                          //Add the request to the batch
      requestBatch.addCallback(batchCallback);               //Set the callback for the Batch Request
      //Check network session opened and permissions
      //codice sospeso
      if(Session.getActiveSession().isOpened() && hasPublishPermission() && isNetworkAvailable()) {
         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Session is opened, I have permission, Network is On", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         requestBatch.executeAsync();
      }
      else if (Session.getActiveSession().isOpened() && isNetworkAvailable()){
         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "I dont have Permissions: " + Session.getActiveSession().getPermissions(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         Session.getActiveSession().requestNewPublishPermissions(new NewPermissionsRequest((SocialSharingActivity)getActivity(), "publish_actions"));
         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Permissions: " + Session.getActiveSession().getPermissions(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
      else if (Session.getActiveSession().isOpened() && hasPublishPermission()) {
         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Check your status connection.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


      }

      else {
         Intent loginIntent = new Intent((SocialSharingActivity)getActivity(),FbLoginActivity.class);
         startActivity(loginIntent);

      }



   }



     private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {  
          ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);  
          NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();  
          return activeNetworkInfo != null;  
      } 

       private boolean hasPublishPermission() {
          Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
          return session != null && session.getPermissions().contains("publish_actions");
      }   


    }
```

Comment: Are you opening the session initially elsewhere (in another activity)? It's likely that the session opening did not complete (you didn't override the onActivityResult?), and that's resulting in this error message.

Comment: Yes I initially open the Session in another activity. I dont understand how override onActivityResult. I dont use in my code startActivityForResult(intent) and for that I dont understand why and how I do override onActivityResult().

Comment: When you call Session.open, the Session object will call startActivityForResult using either the Activity or Fragment you gave it while constructing the Session. So in that same activity or fragment, you need to override the onActivityResult and call session.onActivityResult.